# R apply breaks for non-numeric parameters

Tags: r, apply

I lack a good understanding of the `apply` function which is possibly leading to an error message while looping over a dataframe **where one column is a character**.

I am using `apply` by passing rows of a dataframe to my user defined function (UDF).

All works well when the columns of the dataframe are all `numeric`.

When I change one of the columns to character, then my UDF still works if I pass rows of the dataframe one-by-one.

**However** as soon as I use `apply` then I get this error:

> non-numeric argument to binary operator

Here is an example of code that illustrates the problem:

Define a UDF:

```
UDF <- function(x){return(x[1] + x[2])}
```

Define a dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,2), col2 = c(3,4), col3 = c(5,6))

x
  col1 col2 col3
    1    3    5
    2    4    6
```

Now if I use apply, it works:

```
apply(x,1,FUN = UDF)
[1] 4 6
```

If I change col3 (take note col3 is not used in the UDF) to be a `character` via `x$col3 <- as.character(x$col3)` and I pass one row to the UDF it still works:

```
UDF(x[1,])
  col1
1    4
```

But if I use `apply` on this dataframe, then it breaks and gives an eror saying that it can't plus `x[1]` and `x[2]`:

```
apply(x,1,FUN = UDF)
```

> Error in x[1] + x[2] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `apply` works with matrices (and arrays). If you use `apply` with a dara frame, it is converted to a matrix of the most general type. The character type is more general than the numeric type. Thus, *all* values will become character strings (for which the function `UDF` is not working) if at least one character column is present in the data frame.

To avoid this behavior, you can use `by` instead:

```
by(x, seq(nrow(x)), UDF)
# [1] 4
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# [1] 6
```

---

Another option is `rowwise` in package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% rowwise %>% UDF
#   col1
# 1    4
# 2    6
```